# Parsing the response from an XMLHttpRequest (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm getting a JSON response from an XMLHttpRequest that is formatted like this:

```
<response xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">{"serial": "163636364", "type": "Orange", "image ": "Orange.png", "major-version": "25.003", "logged-in": "", "log-entry": "no"}</response>
```

And I'm trying to parse it using JSON.parse with this callback function:

```
ajax_machine_info(serial, callback);
function callback(response) {
console.log(response);
json_response=JSON.parse(this.reponse);
document.getElementById('serial-element').innerHTML = json_reponse.serial;}"
```

But I get errors such as this in Chrome:

```
VM2291:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at callback ((index):63)
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange ((index):29)`
```

This is the code I'm using to make the http request:

```html
//<![CDATA[ 
function fetchURI(uri, callback) {
  var request;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { request = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
  else {
    try { request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) {
      try { request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } catch (ee) {
        request = null;
      }}}
  if (!request) alert("Browser couldn't make a request object.");

  request.open('GET', uri, true);
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState != 4) return;
    if (((request.status>=200) && (request.status<300)) || (request.status == 304)) {
      var data = request.responseXML;
      if (callback!=null) { callback(data); }
    }
    else { 
      alert('Error while fetching URI ' + uri);
    }
  }
  request.send(null);
  delete request;
}

function ajax_call(func, callback, args) {
  var uri = '/ajax/' + encodeURIComponent(func) + '/';
  var i;
  if (args.length > 0) {
    uri += '?'
    for (i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
      if (i > 0) { uri += '&' };
      uri += 'arg' + i + '=' + encodeURIComponent(args[i]);
    }
  }
  fetchURI(uri, callback);
}

function ajax_machine_info (serial, callback) {
    ajax_call('MACHINE-INFO', callback, [serial]);
}
//]]>
```

---

Can you see what's going wrong?

Comment: seems like the server is returning you a html object instead of json

Comment: take away the <response> tags... It's not JSON and therefore the parsing will go wrong. The error and cause are quite clear, here.

Comment: What's the best way to do that?

Comment: `response.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue` is the way to go.